# Intellij IDEA for loop code assistant Netbeans alike

Tags: java, intellij-idea, netbeans

I'm still more than sure that for example "for loop" as well as "try/catch" snippets more superior comparing to IntelliJ.
Is there any possibility to simulate it on IntelliJ ?

[image: Netbeans for loop][image: Netbeans try/catch]

Comment: I think this is not duplicate question. I'm completely aware of the shortcuts and possibilities of both IDE's.
My observation is that Netbeans has superior way to intelligently propose what concrete iteration may be applied to a collection I'm working on.
On the other hand, Idea seems that doesn't have that possibility, as it just mechanically propose e.g. iteration type on the collection.
For example, Idea does not recognize a Map and and does not infer a proper loop, e.g. Map.Entry<,> which we all use very much.

Comment: But what do you expect then? What makes you think that IntelliJ can do better? Btw: I would suggest that you turn to their forums, too. Their support is typically very responsive when you ask for specific problems. Even when it turns out to be a feature request?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! Just text "for" and he'll give you some options. Can do a for, fori (for + iterator), foreach...

But that's just a easy way to do a work, but isn't it extremelly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In IntelliJ you should be be able to hit control(for windows, mac is CMD) j, and you should get a little popup menu with some shortcuts. The try catch is not in there though, but you can start typing try and a shortcut should popup

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Code completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html)

Write the `list name` `dot` `for` and then press `ctrl+space`

```
List<String> abc = new ArrayList<>();
abc.for <press ctrl+space>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. However it is not as friendly as it should be.

Comment: Give me a shortcut for the, let's say : Map<Integer, MyCustomBean>.
I want to iterate over map's entryset.

Comment: @dobrivoje, you can do **``map.entrySet().for <press ctrl+space>``**

Comment: Ok. It's a little harder, but it's important that exist some way :)